# Conditional independence and union of two events?

Tags: probability

So, let A and B be two independent events, and C = A ∪ B. Conditional on C, are A and B independent? I assume not, but I fail to see a way to perfectly demonstrate why.

Comment: Can you at least write down what you need to test to determine whether $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given that $C = A \cup B$ has occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disproving the claim "Conditional on $C$, the events $A$ and $B$ independent" entails producing a counterexample, not proving something.

A simple counterexample: flip two coins, let $A$ be the event that the first coin is heads, let $B$ be the event that the second coin is heads. Then $C$ is the event that there is at least one heads. Then $$P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(\text{both heads})/P(\text{at least one heads}) = 1/3$$ while $$P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C) = (2/3)(2/3)=4/9.$$